# Deleted post with downvoted and Serial downvote reversed

Tags: support, deleted-questions, serial-voting

If I got downvote on my question and I delete my question? and if it was Serial downvote. will I get my downvote reputation back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you only get your reputation back *once*.

Either for the serial downvote reversal, *or* the deletion, which ever comes first, but not for both.